# ADSF Secured Web Application Calling Web Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif, adfs2.0

I have Active Directory Federation Services 2.0 all setup and ready to work, but I have a scenario that falls outside pretty much everything I've read on enabling a relying party application. The 2 scenarios that are well documented involve A) Passive authentication for a web site or B) Using a thick client that's authenticated for calling web services.

My scenario is as follows: I have a web application that calls WCF services via Net.TCP for data access. I need to use ADFS 2.0 to secure each WCF call with a secure token.

I also can't use use the passive method of authenticating with ADFS from the web site (security restrictions outside my control).

**So my question is, is it possible to manually request a secure token from ADFS via a web site, then use that same token to call my WFC service methods?**

Comment: How are you authenticating the Web Application, with ADFS or some other method?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://travisspencer.com/blog/2009/03/caching-tokens-to-avoid-calls.html. 
In this blog post it is described how to cache security tokens for wcf service calls.

I think it should also be possible to "inject" an already fetched token in the described "CacheSecurityTokenProvider".